# User page "member for" problem on Meta SO, not given full credit

Tags: support, profile-page

Many users on Meta SO are being given full credit on their user page for being members for 10 or 11 months.  I'm a bit jealous.  Maybe I associated my accounts incorrectly or something because I'm only being given credit as being a member for a few days.  Should I be getting full credit on my user page like the other users with regards to how long I've been a member of the SO community (i.e. 11 months)?

Comment: Send an email to the team, using the contact us link at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of us got auto-migrated when the site was created.

Actually, i believe *most* active accounts were initially auto-migrated. Then came the introduction of the account association feature, and the deletion of accounts that hadn't been associated already.

I suspect one or more of the SO developers understands how things really work in the fallout from that whole mess, but suffice to say: if you weren't already active on Meta when it happened, it's too late now...

**Edit:** they've apparently fixed this now - everyone gets the more recent, "real" join dates...

Comment: I just don't really care about my 'status' on Meta (profile or rep). It is just a nice place to sit, read about upcoming features and see people freak out about deleting their account.

Comment: Well, yeah... It's not like you get any benefit from having a bigger "member for" number. Pretty sure if anyone tried to pull seniority based on something as stupid as that they'd be laughed off the page...